# ModelForm field attrs

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

According to the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/), a modelform field accepts `attrs`.  When I attempt to apply `attrs` I get

> TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'attrs'

The form I'm attempting to make is pretty simple, I just want to apply style to it.  What am I doing wrong?

forms.py

```
from django import forms

from .models import ServiceReportModel


class ServiceReportCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ServiceReportModel
        fields = [
            'request_number',
            'request_reason',
            'actions_taken',
        ]


class ServiceReportUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ServiceReportModel
        fields = [
            'report_number',
            'request_number',
            'request_reason',
            'actions_taken',
        ]
        widgets = {
            'report_number': forms.CharField(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'request_number': forms.CharField(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'request_reason': forms.CharField(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'actions_taken': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }
```

views.py

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

from .forms import ServiceReportCreateForm, ServiceReportUpdateForm
from .models import ServiceReportModel


class ReportCreateView(CreateView):
    form_class = ServiceReportCreateForm
    model = ServiceReportModel


class ReportCreateView(UpdateView):
    form_class = ServiceReportUpdateForm
    model = ServiceReportModel


class ReportDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = ServiceReportModel
    success_url = reverse_lazy('reports-list')
```

models.py

```
import uuid
from django.urls import reverse
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm
from main import models as main_models
from customers import models as customers_models


class ServiceReportModel(models.Model):
    report_number = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    request_number = models.ForeignKey(ServiceRequestModel,
                                       on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                                       null=True,
                                       related_name='s_report_number'
                                      )
    reported_by = models.ForeignKey(main_models.MyUser, editable=False, related_name='reports')
    reported_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(main_models.MyUser, editable=True, blank=True, null=True, related_name='+')
    updated_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    request_reason = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    actions_taken = models.TextField()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('service-report', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fields do not accept `attrs`, widgets do. And similarly the `widgets` dictionary expects widgets not fields. You should use `TextInput`.

Comment: Yeah you're right.  Thank you.  I noticed it after I already posted, but good info none-the-less :)