# Use custom css in django forms

Tags: django-forms, django-templates

Hey I am working on blog project and I have created a form to add post and I want to use my css with froms.In add post form there is a image field to upload image .

**forms.py**

```
class AddPostForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = {'title_image'}
        labels ={
            'title_image':'Upload Main  Image'
        }
```

**addpost.html**

```
<form action= "#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <div class="file-upload-wrapper"  data-text="Select your file!">
      {{ form.title_image }}
    </div>
</form>
```

how to use my css classes I already tried widgets and got error

```
'title_image' : forms.ImageField(attrs ={'class':'form-control'})
```

did something like this but got error

**Field.**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'attrs'**

Thanks and any advice will be helpful.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47502207/7106343, Fields do not accept attrs, widgets do.

Comment: @AD yeah i got FileInput is widget thanks for the help